# how to replace element text with element title in jquery?

Tags: jquery, azureportal

I need to swap out the text of a class (timeago) with the title dynamically. there will be multiple divs containing this class it could be 1 or it could be 1000

here is an example:

```
<abbr class="timeago" data-datetime="2022-10-30T18:54:39Z" title="10/30/2022 11:54 AM">15 days ago</abbr>
```

i appreciate the help

$('.timeago').attr('title', $('.timeago').text());

replaces titles with text but i need to do the opposite and for all .timeago classes, when i apply :firstchild to test it is still grabbing all the .timeago's text that exist..

is there an easy way to make this work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
// jQuery 1
$(".timeago").each(function(){$(this).text($(this).attr("title"))});

// jQuery 2
$(".timeago1").each(function(){this.textContent = this.title});

// Vanilla-JS
document.querySelectorAll(".timeago2").forEach(e => e.textContent = e.title);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<abbr class="timeago" data-datetime="2022-10-30T18:54:39Z" title="10/30/2022 11:54 AM">15 days ago</abbr>
<abbr class="timeago" data-datetime="2022-10-30T18:54:39Z" title="10/30/2022 11:54 AM">15 days ago</abbr>
<br>
<abbr class="timeago1" data-datetime="2022-10-30T18:54:39Z" title="10/30/2022 11:54 AM">15 days ago</abbr>
<abbr class="timeago1" data-datetime="2022-10-30T18:54:39Z" title="10/30/2022 11:54 AM">15 days ago</abbr>
<br>
<abbr class="timeago2" data-datetime="2022-10-30T18:54:39Z" title="10/30/2022 11:54 AM">15 days ago</abbr>
<abbr class="timeago2" data-datetime="2022-10-30T18:54:39Z" title="10/30/2022 11:54 AM">15 days ago</abbr>
```

Comment: for some reason this is reverting back to displaying "days ago" after about a minute

Comment: i think bootstrapTable is auto refreshing every 60 sec but cant figure out how to keep this from happening